# Suppose that $A,B,C$ are finite sets, and that $B \cup C=A$ and $B \cap C=\varnothing$. Then $|A|=|B|+|C|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Please check if my proof is fine! Thank you for your help!

Theorem:

> Suppose that $A,B,C$ are finite sets, and that $B \cup C=A$ and $B \cap C=\varnothing$. Then $|A|=|B|+|C|$. Here $|X|=\operatorname{card}(X)$.

My proof:

> Since $B,C$ are finite, then there exist $g:B \to I_n$ and $h:C \to I_m$ such that $g,h$ are bijective.
>
> Let $k:C \to I_{m+n}$ such that $k(c)=h(c)+n$, then $k:C \to I_{m+n} \setminus I_{n}$ is bijective.
>
> Let $h:A \to I_{m+n}$ such that $h(a)=g(a)$ for all $a \in B$ and $h(a)=k(a)$ for all $a \in C$.
>
> Since $B \cap C=\varnothing$, then $(a \in A \implies a \in B$ or $a \in C$, but not both) then $h:A \to I_{m+n}$ is bijective.
>
> Thus $|A|=m+n=|B|+|C|$.

Comment: You haven't mentioned *why* $B\cap C=\varnothing$ means $B$, $C$ should be mapped to the intervals of the natural numbers you used.

Comment: Alternatively, prove that [$|B \cup C|=|B|+|C|-|B \cap C|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful concepts:

In general, if $f: B \to D$ and $g: C \to D$ are any two functions we can't naturally define a function on $B \cup C$ by 'gluing' the two function together unless they agree on the intersection $B \cap C$.

In the special case where $B \cap C = \emptyset$ we are in business:

$\tag 1 h: B \cup C \to D \text{ where } h(x) = f(x) \text{ when } x \in B \text{ and } h(x) = g(x) \text{ when } x \in C$

Moreover, $h \text{ is injective iff } f \text{ is injective and } g \text{ is injective and the images of } f \text{ and } g \text{ are disjoint}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track so far.

You still need to prove that the function  $  h:A \to I_{m+n}$ is well-defined and  bijective.

You have not used the fact that $A\cap B =\phi $.

Please add some detail to your proof and it will be fine.